# Cloud Datastore Emulator Can't Find Java on Mac

Tags: java, macos, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

running `gcloud beta emulators datastore start` produces error:

`ERROR: (gcloud.beta.emulators.datastore.start) The java executable on your PATH is not a Java 7+ JRE. The Google Cloud Datastore emulator requires a Java 7+ JRE installed and on your system PATH`

the problem is, I do have java installed. When running `java -version` I get:

`java version "9.0.1"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)`

macOS version: 10.12.6

I reinstalling java and rebooting, nothing works

Any help?

Comment: I have the same problem on Ubuntu.
No idea why this was downvoted without comment. It's a legit question, isn't it?

Comment: @trollkotze I believe it is, thanks for the support

Comment: I solved it somehow. I don't remember all the details, but the problem seemed to be that the cloud datastore package had the Oracle Java 9 JRE and a package called "oracle-java9-set-default" as a dependency.
Apparently the version checking goes wrong with that java implementation for some reason. (I think it does not react to `java --version`, but only to `java -version` - maybe that's the reason.)
So, despite having another JRE installed previously (OpenJDK 8, I think), Cloud Datastore wanted to install Oracle Java 9 and set that as default, too. I did manage to get it working by ...

Comment: purging all remains of java, reinstalling the OpenJDK JRE 8, forcing the installation of cloud datastore without those dependencies. (I think I had to do something like `dpkg -i --force-dependencies` on the deb package manually downloaded or something, but am not quite sure anymore.)
There was another more "elegant" way I found somewhere on SO I believe. That was removing cloud datastore emulator (and maybe other gcloud stuff), then doing `apt update` then editing something in the downloaded new package indexes to remove those dependencies, and thus being able to install through `apt upgrade`

Comment: But the dependencies will appear again with the next `apt update`, I think.

Comment: thanks, but it seems this solution will work on linux only. I'll try removing and installing on my mac, and see if it works

Comment: I just had to delete everything and reinstall, and it worked